# Sending messages in Multi-tenant application using Spring Boot WebSocket RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, multi-tenant, spring-websocket

I am new to RabbitMQ and need to understand how to send message to specific user of specfic company. We are using Spring Boot, WebSocket, RabbitMQ and Angular. We have multitenant application in which there are multiple companies registered and in each company there are multiple users.

Currently I am able to send message to specific user using **/queue/user** but I want to send message to user like **/queue/{company}/user**.

I understand that stomp broker relay has endpoints like **"/queue", "/topic", "/exchange", "/amq/queue"**.

Is it possible to create company specific queues and in that company specfic queue, I need to send user specfic message.

Below is my working configuration for user specific messages :

WebSocketConfiguration.java

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/notification").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay(/queue).setRelayHost(localhost).setRelayPort(61613)
            .setClientLogin(guest).setClientPasscode(guest);
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(/app);
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix(/user);
}
```

Message sending class :

```
private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

public NotificationServiceImpl(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
    this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
}

@Override
public void notify(Notification notification, List<String> usernames) {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/user" + username, notification);
}
```

Angular Code :

```
const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:9090/notification');
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

const _this = this;
this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
  _this.setConnected(true);
  console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

  _this.stompClient.subscribe('/queue/userjohndoe', function (notify) {
    _this.showGreeting(JSON.parse(notify.body).notificationMessage);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: @pacman What I did is I added my company name before the username.
For example /queue/user{companyName}.{userName}